# Dnn 2sxc Blog Module sub-directory

Tags: 2sxc, dotnetnuke-8

I am testing out DNN 8 and am using the blog app and content management from 2sxc (great module, BTW!).

I have the recent blog post listed on a page sub-directory called '/articles'. But I also wanted some of them listed on the home page as well. When I add the app or module to the home page the url is '/home/post/post-title-here' while on the /articles page the urls are '/articles/post/post-title-here'. This creates the illusion that I have two directories with duplicate blog posts (which probably will get me some dings for SEO for duplicating the same content).

How do I get the app to use the common directory '/articles' regardless of where I put the module/app on the site? I've looked at settings all over and don't see anything that pops out at me. Also not sure if this is a DNN setting or a setting specifically to the extension. Finally, I'd like to be able to keep the year/date/month parts of my url as well as they were on the old site. I assume making that change would probably be similar with the solution to my original question. If that's a different fix, then let me know and I'll put it into a new thread. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This question is basically about the blog-app. Now if I understand you correctly, your question is "Can I have multiple lists on various pages, but all of them still link to my main details page". The answer is yes, but the exact solution depends a bit on what you need.

So basically there is a setting in the app-settings to define the main page. I believe it's empty by default, so that the blog-app works automatically without you having to configure anything. But AFAIK if you set that, all blog-details-links will use that as the only source.